# How do you rotate a circle about a point in JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt

I am trying to rotate a circle around a separate point in a program. right now I can get the circle to rotate but it slowly starts getting closer and closer to the point it's rotating from. I am trying to do this using JPanel and implementing it as a rectangle.

```
package WoffindenZone;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Protector extends Rectangle{
double Velocity;
int speed = 3;
Protector(int x, int y, int PROTECTOR_DIAMETER){
    super(x,y,PROTECTOR_DIAMETER,PROTECTOR_DIAMETER);
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        setDirection(speed);
        move();
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        setDirection(speed);
        move();
    }
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        setDirection(0);
        move();
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        setDirection(0);
        move();
    }
}
public void setDirection(int Direction){
    Velocity = Direction*Math.PI/180;
}

public void move(){
    x = (int)Math.round(500 + Math.cos(Velocity) * (x-500) - Math.sin(Velocity) * (y-((1000*0.5555)/2)));
    y = (int)Math.round(((1000*0.5555)/2) + Math.sin(Velocity) * (x-500) + Math.cos(Velocity) * (y-((1000*0.5555)/2)));
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
}
public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillOval(x,y,width,height);
}
```

Comment: Java naming conventions use capital letters for the names of classes; variables and methods start with a small letter (direction). Constants use all caps and snake case.

Comment: @NomadMaker At first I had an xDirection and yDirection and made the circle move freely so when I was changing stuff I forgot to change the d to a lowercase. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Store `double` values for `x` and `y`, and use the `double` values each time you calculate the new values.  Only round/cast to `int` when you're actually calling `fillOval`.

Comment: Create a Circle class that holds a center java.awt.Point and an int radius.  Create a circle to draw and a circle to rotate the drawing circle around the rotating circle.  Draw on a drawing JPanel.  See the Oracle tutorial [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to see an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use a rotation instance of an `AffineTransform`. See [`getRotateInstance(theta,anchorx,anchory)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getRotateInstance(double,double,double)) for details.

> Returns a transform that rotates coordinates around an anchor point. This operation is equivalent to translating the coordinates so that the anchor point is at the origin (S1), then rotating them about the new origin (S2), and finally translating so that the intermediate origin is restored to the coordinates of the original anchor point (S3).

Answer (score 0):

> How do you rotate a circle about a point in JPanel?

Here's how I rotate a circle about a point in a `JPanel`.

[image: Rotate Circle GUI]

I don't know how to make an animated GIF.  Just imagine the blue circle rotating clockwise around the center of the drawing `JPanel`.

So, let's start at the beginning.  Basically, I have a circle rotating on the circumference of another circle.  So, I create a `Circle` model class from plain Java.

```
public class Circle {
    
    private final int radius;
    
    private final Color color;
    
    private Point center;
    
    public Circle(int radius, Color color) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
    }
    
    public Point calculateCircumferencePoint(int theta) {
        double radians = Math.toRadians(theta);
        int x = center.x + (int) Math.round(Math.cos(radians) * radius);
        int y = center.y + (int) Math.round(Math.sin(radians) * radius);
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
    
    public void setCenter(int x, int y) {
        this.center = new Point(x, y);
    }

    public void setCenter(Point center) {
        this.center = center;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public Point getCenter() {
        return center;
    }
    
}
```

The class consists of basic getters and setters.  I make the radius and color `final` because they don't change value in this Java application.

The `calculateCircumferencePoint` method is the only interesting method.  It takes an `int` angle in degrees, and calculates the point on the circumference represented by that angle, rounded to the nearest X and Y integer points.

Next, we create two `Circle` instances, an inner circle and an outer circle.  Here's the class constructor setting the preferred size of the drawing area, the inner circle, and the outer circle.  We start the outer circle at zero degrees (to the right);

```
private Circle innerCircle;
private Circle outerCircle;

private Dimension drawingPanelSize;

public RotateCircle() {
    this.drawingPanelSize = new Dimension(400, 400);
    int innerCircleRadius = drawingPanelSize.width / 4;
    int centerX = drawingPanelSize.width / 2;
    int centerY = drawingPanelSize.height / 2;
    int outerCircleRadius = drawingPanelSize.width / 10;
    
    this.innerCircle = new Circle(innerCircleRadius, null);
    this.innerCircle.setCenter(centerX, centerY);
    this.outerCircle = new Circle(outerCircleRadius, Color.BLUE);
    Point point = innerCircle.calculateCircumferencePoint(0);
    this.outerCircle.setCenter(point);
}
```

Now, we can start coding the GUI.  First, we start the Java application by calling the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that we create and execute the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Next, we define the `JFrame`.  Here's the code we have so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RotateCircle());
}

private Animation animation;

private Circle innerCircle;
private Circle outerCircle;

private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

private Dimension drawingPanelSize;

public RotateCircle() {
    this.drawingPanelSize = new Dimension(400, 400);
    int innerCircleRadius = drawingPanelSize.width / 4;
    int centerX = drawingPanelSize.width / 2;
    int centerY = drawingPanelSize.height / 2;
    int outerCircleRadius = drawingPanelSize.width / 10;
    
    this.innerCircle = new Circle(innerCircleRadius, null);
    this.innerCircle.setCenter(centerX, centerY);
    this.outerCircle = new Circle(outerCircleRadius, Color.BLUE);
    Point point = innerCircle.calculateCircumferencePoint(0);
    this.outerCircle.setCenter(point);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rotate Circle");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(drawingPanelSize, 
            outerCircle);
    frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
    animation = new Animation(0);
    new Thread(animation).start();
}
```

The `JFrame` methods must be called in a certain order.  This is the order I use for most of my SWwing applications.

I pack the `JFrame`.  I don't set a `JFrame` size.  I let the [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) set the size of my `JFrame`.  The default layout of a `JFrame` content pane is a `BorderLayout`.  I put my drawing `JPanel` in the center of the `BorderLayout`.

Next, I create the drawing `JPanel`.

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private Circle circle;
    
    public DrawingPanel(Dimension size, Circle circle) {
        this.circle = circle;
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setPreferredSize(size);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        
        Point center = circle.getCenter();
        int radius = circle.getRadius();
        int diameter = radius + radius;
        g2d.setColor(circle.getColor());
        g2d.fillOval(center.x - radius, center.y - radius, 
                diameter, diameter);
    }
    
}
```

All the drawing `JPanel` does is paint a `Circle` object.  Pretty straightforward.

The `fillOval` method paints an oval from the upper left hand corner.  We calculate the upper left hand point from the center point.

The responsibility for calculating and updating the outer circle center point falls to my controller class, the `Animation` class.  I use a simple loop to update the theta angle, calculate the new outer circle center point, paint the outer circle, and wait a period of time.

Here's that code.

```
public class Animation implements Runnable {
    
    private int theta;
    
    public Animation(int theta) {
        this.theta = theta;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            theta++;
            theta = (theta >= 360) ? 0 : theta;
            
            Point center = innerCircle.calculateCircumferencePoint(theta);
            outerCircle.setCenter(center);
            repaint();
            sleep(30L);
        }
    }
    
    private void repaint() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drawingPanel.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
    
    private void sleep(long duration) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(duration);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

The `Animation` `repaint` method makes the call to the drawing `JPanel` `repaint` method inside another `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the drawing happens on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Finally, here's the complete, runnable, example.  I used inner classes so I could post the code as one block, and you can copy and run this code as one block.  Generally, classes should be in separate files and for a more complex GUI, separate packages.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class RotateCircle implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RotateCircle());
    }
    
    private Animation animation;
    
    private Circle innerCircle;
    private Circle outerCircle;
    
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    private Dimension drawingPanelSize;
    
    public RotateCircle() {
        this.drawingPanelSize = new Dimension(400, 400);
        int innerCircleRadius = drawingPanelSize.width / 4;
        int centerX = drawingPanelSize.width / 2;
        int centerY = drawingPanelSize.height / 2;
        int outerCircleRadius = drawingPanelSize.width / 10;
        
        this.innerCircle = new Circle(innerCircleRadius, null);
        this.innerCircle.setCenter(centerX, centerY);
        this.outerCircle = new Circle(outerCircleRadius, Color.BLUE);
        Point point = innerCircle.calculateCircumferencePoint(0);
        this.outerCircle.setCenter(point);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rotate Circle");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(drawingPanelSize, 
                outerCircle);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        animation = new Animation(0);
        new Thread(animation).start();
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private Circle circle;
        
        public DrawingPanel(Dimension size, Circle circle) {
            this.circle = circle;
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setPreferredSize(size);
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            
            Point center = circle.getCenter();
            int radius = circle.getRadius();
            int diameter = radius + radius;
            g2d.setColor(circle.getColor());
            g2d.fillOval(center.x - radius, center.y - radius, 
                    diameter, diameter);
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Animation implements Runnable {
        
        private int theta;
        
        public Animation(int theta) {
            this.theta = theta;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                theta++;
                theta = (theta >= 360) ? 0 : theta;
                
                Point center = innerCircle.calculateCircumferencePoint(theta);
                outerCircle.setCenter(center);
                repaint();
                sleep(30L);
            }
        }
        
        private void repaint() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    drawingPanel.repaint();
                }
            });
        }
        
        private void sleep(long duration) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(duration);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Circle {
        
        private final int radius;
        
        private final Color color;
        
        private Point center;
        
        public Circle(int radius, Color color) {
            this.radius = radius;
            this.color = color;
        }
        
        public Point calculateCircumferencePoint(int theta) {
            double radians = Math.toRadians(theta);
            int x = center.x + (int) Math.round(Math.cos(radians) * radius);
            int y = center.y + (int) Math.round(Math.sin(radians) * radius);
            return new Point(x, y);
        }
        
        public void setCenter(int x, int y) {
            this.center = new Point(x, y);
        }

        public void setCenter(Point center) {
            this.center = center;
        }

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public Point getCenter() {
            return center;
        }
        
    }

}
```